# Flash Icon on FabricJS

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

How exactly do I create this icon using FabricJS?

[image]

I tried using Path and Pathgroup on [this](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#path_and_pathgroup) page but I don't understand how the parameters work in `new.fabric.Path('..')`.

Using `fabric.Image` is not an option as I intend to export the canvas as SVG and an image file's data isn't copied in SVG file.

Comment: Do you only need to create this flash icon or any other icons too?

Comment: Just this one will do

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following SVG Path Data to create the flash icon, using **[`fabric.Path`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Path.html)** class ...

```
M795 2528 c-3 -18 -46 -301 -95 -628 -49 -327 -92 -610 -95 -627 l-6
-33 180 -2 179 -3 -214 -604 c-118 -332 -212 -606 -210 -608 2 -2 341 360 753
804 l749 808 -277 5 -277 5 157 400 c86 220 166 426 178 458 l22 57 -519 0
-519 0 -6 -32z
```

basically, **`new.fabric.Path('..')`** takes absolute svg path data as a parameter.

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var path = new fabric.Path('M795 2528 c-3 -18 -46 -301 -95 -628 -49 -327 -92 -610 -95 -627 l-6 -33 180 -2 179 -3 -214 -604 c-118 -332 -212 -606 -210 -608 2 -2 341 360 753 804 l749 808 -277 5 -277 5 157 400 c86 220 166 426 178 458 l22 57 -519 0 -519 0 -6 -32z');

path.set({
   left: 100,
   top: 100,
   flipY: true,
   originX: 'center',
   originY: 'center'
});
path.scaleToWidth(100);
path.scaleToHeight(100);

canvas.add(path);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
canvas{border: 1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```